# Can i send a SOAP response without SOAP envelop and body tags, Just a Plain XML

Tags: c#, wcf, datacontract, messagecontract

I'm sending the response as XML document from my WCF service.

```
  <AnalysisResponse>
   <AnalysisResult>
    <Note>0</Note>
    <Summary/>
   </AnalysisResult>
  </AnalysisResponse>
```

But when test this using SOAP UI, I get.

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
 <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
   xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <GetDataResponse>
     <GetDataResult>
      <AnalysisResponse>
       <AnalysisResult>
        <Note>0</Note>
        <Summary/>
       </AnalysisResult>
      </AnalysisResponse>
     </GetDataResult>
    </GetDataResponse>
   </s:Body>
  </s:Envelope>
```

I just want the response what i'm sending from the WCF service without SOAP auto generated tags.

```
<AnalysisResponse>
 <AnalysisResult>
  <Note>0</Note>
  <Summary/>
 </AnalysisResult>
</AnalysisResponse>
```

Comment: It wouldn't be SOAP response message anymore :)

Comment: you wouldn't see any auto generated tags when you create a proxy client and use it